# Visual Studio crashes on opening Designer for a C++\CLI Form using .NET Framework 2.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c++-cli

I have a Windows Form written in C++\CLI. When I try to open the form in Visual Studio(by saying 'View Designer') then I observe that Visual Studio crashes.

Following is the Windows Applications Logs -

.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.4963 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (768FB727) (800703e9)

Note :

1. My project is built to use .NET Framework 2.0
2. OS - Windows Server 2008 x64
3. I have tried reinstalling VS2005 and .NET Framework 2.0 without any success

Comment: Though I am able to successfully compile and run the application

Comment: Do you have any custom controls that have design time code in them? Or maybe some third party controls?

Comment: I do have custom controls and third party controls in my form... But I do not face any such issues while opening the form (in Design View) in another system having the same OS.

Comment: Stack trace then, see what's the deepest place where the error happens.

Comment: Do I really need to Stack trace as the same form opens up well on other machine ? If so, how to do it ?

Note: 
.NET Runtime version on this machine is 2.0.50727.4927 which is different from the one on which it fails. (Failing machine has .NET Runtime 2.0.52727.4963)

Comment: Sorry for the typo above :

Failing machine has .NET Runtime 2.0.50727.4963

Comment: You apparently do need to find out yourself what the problem is since it doesn't seem to be something common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@linkerro - You were right, the problem was actually in some third party user controls that my form was loading at design time.

I used Assembly Binding Log Viewer (fuslogvw.exe) to find out what were the bind failures.

Comment: It is not a binding failure, it crashes on a StackOverflow error.  Easily triggered by a mistake in your code.

Comment: Okay Hans... So this is how I solved the problem...

I had some of the third party controls that I am using in my application. These third party controls are .NET assemblies that I refer in my project. I have added static reference to the assemblies     . Hence, my application is able to compile and run fine.

But when the Designer tries to load the assembly, it was not able to  find the assembly in the local folder of devenv.exe and not even in the GAC. Hence it failed. Installing the assemblies in the GAC resolved the problem.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'm not about to argue with a solution.  Maybe your exception handling is borken.  Just important to note what the real error code says for anybody that finds this question back some day.